# AES decrypt in php

Tags: php, encryption, base64, aes, decoding

I am new to AES but from what I have found there are several modes (ECB,CBC, etc.) and different modes need different initialization vector requirements, blocks, and encodings. I am trying to decode the following

```
Xrb9YtT7cHUdpHYIvEWeJIAbkxWUtCNcjdzOMgyxJzU/vW9xHivdEDFKeszC93B6MMkhctR35e+YkmYI5ejMf5ofNxaiQcZbf3OBBsngfWUZxfvnrE2u1lD5+R6cn88vk4+mwEs3WoAht1CAkjr7P+fRIaCTckWLaF9ZAgo1/rvYA8EGDc+uXgWv9KvYpDDsCd1JStrD96IACN3DNuO28lVOsKrhcEWhDjAx+yh72wM=
```

using php and the (text) key "043j9fmd38jrr4dnej3FD11111111111" with mode CBC and an IV of all zeros.  I am able to get it to work with [this tool](http://isv.appspot.com/app/enc) but can't get it in php.  Here is the code I am using:

```
function decrypt_data($data, $iv, $key) {
    $data   = base64_decode($data);
    $cypher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

    // initialize encryption handle
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cypher, $key, $iv) != -1) {
            // decrypt
            $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cypher, $data);

            // clean up
            mcrypt_generic_deinit($cypher);
            mcrypt_module_close($cypher);

            return $decrypted;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I think I may be missing something relating to base 64 encoding or turning the key into binary first. I have tried decoding many things and all I can produce is gibberish.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You've got a base64-encoded string. It'll have to be decoded back to binary garbage before you feed it to mcrypt.

Comment: I had tried that... and it may be part of it  but I am still getting gibberish even doing that... I will update my question to show it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the tool itself does not say how exactly it's encrypted. And you can't set the IV either so it's hard to get the parameters right (because they have to be equal).

After some guesswork I found out the following:

- The IV is prepended to the ciphertext
- The ciphertext is encrypted with aes-128-cbc

So you have to modify the code:

```
function decrypt_data($data, $iv, $key) {
    $cypher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

    if(is_null($iv)) {
        $ivlen = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($cypher);
        $iv = substr($data, 0, $ivlen);
        $data = substr($data, $ivlen);
    }

    // initialize encryption handle
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cypher, $key, $iv) != -1) {
            // decrypt
            $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cypher, $data);

            // clean up
            mcrypt_generic_deinit($cypher);
            mcrypt_module_close($cypher);

            return $decrypted;
    }

    return false;
}

$ctext = "Xrb9YtT7cHUdpHYIvEWeJIAbkxWUtCNcjdzOMgyxJzU/vW9x" .
         "HivdEDFKeszC93B6MMkhctR35e+YkmYI5ejMf5ofNxaiQcZb" .
         "f3OBBsngfWUZxfvnrE2u1lD5+R6cn88vk4+mwEs3WoAht1CA" .
         "kjr7P+fRIaCTckWLaF9ZAgo1/rvYA8EGDc+uXgWv9KvYpDDs" .
         "Cd1JStrD96IACN3DNuO28lVOsKrhcEWhDjAx+yh72wM=";

$key = "043j9fmd38jrr4dnej3FD11111111111";

$res = decrypt_data(base64_decode($ctext), null, $key);
```

I'm not sure why the key length is not used to encrypt it with aes-256-cbc - I've checked out the source of that [as3crypto-library](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) and it kind of supported it, but I would have to debug it to really verify it.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I literally was trying things for hours (including I thought seeing if it was 128 rather than 256). How did you ever find this out?

Comment: ok so more of the story is clear now... I found that the first 16 bytes of the actual data were being interpreted as the IV as you suggested but that meant that by using CBC I am missing the first 16 bytes.  I can however get those bytes by running ECB on them and then merge the two together.